# Pop-up box doesn't show on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a pop-up box show on top of everything when I hover over some city names.
It doesn't seem to overlap with z-index set to 999 and position: absolute, it doesn't even show.
This is jQuery script

```
$(function() {
var moveLeft = 0;
var moveDown = 0;
$('a.popper').hover(function(e) {

    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

    $(target).show();
    moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
    moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);
}, function() {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).hide();
});

$('a.popper').mousemove(function(e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

    leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
    maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
    windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
    windowRight = 0;
    maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);

    if(maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight)
    {
        leftD = maxLeft;
    }

    topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
    maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
    windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
    maxTop = topD;
    windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
    if(maxBottom > windowBottom)
    {
        topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
    } else if(maxTop < windowTop){
        topD = windowTop + 20;
    }

    $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);


});

})(jQuery);
```

This is the CSS

```
.popbox {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
width: 400px;
padding: 10px;
background: #EEEFEB;
color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #4D4F53;
margin: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
}
.popbox h2
{
background-color: #4D4F53;
color:  #E3E5DD;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div id="pop1" class="popbox">
<h2>Youth Academy Bucuresti</h2>
<p>Membri:</p>
</div>
<div id="pop2" class="popbox">
<h2>Youth Academy Piatra Neamt</h2>
<p>Membri</p>
</div>
These are the cities: <a href="#" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1">Bucuresti</a>, <a href="#" class="popper" data-popbox="pop2">Piatra Neamt</a> etc.
```

Seems that without this block of code

```
$('a.popper').mousemove(function(e) {
var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
windowRight = 0;
maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);

if(maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight)
{
    leftD = maxLeft;
}

topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
maxTop = topD;
windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
if(maxBottom > windowBottom)
{
    topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
} else if(maxTop < windowTop){
    topD = windowTop + 20;
}

$(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);


});
```

the pop-up box appear and dissapears just fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: where is your `a` tag with the `popper` class?

Comment: I edited the question now, I didn't format the html code correctly. Sorry

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/xL9j2cyj/

Comment: Maybe you havent loaded the jquery code before the other code. jQuery has to be loaded *always* at the top of the page.

Comment: It is loaded correctly afaik.
http://imgur.com/a/yjioR
In the last photos I show what's happening before hovering and while I'm hovering. Seems that the pop-up box is expanding the window, but not showing.

Comment: to avoid the pop-up window expanding you should change the .popbox css width to auto..

Comment: Did, still not working. Window doesn't expand anymore, but the pop-up isn't still showing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the JS Console for errors. There are some.
However, it's not a good idea to let the JavaScript self execute before anything is ready.

Instead try to hook it all up in the document ready Event.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  Your foo..
});
```

I have putted it all together in the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wh2zxd2z/

Is this the expected result?

Comment: Still not showing. 
imgur.com/a/yjioR
jQuery is loaded correctly
I made the jQuery script as you wrote it, nothing.
Look at the last two photos of the album.

Comment: In the First picture I have noticed, that you have loaded jQuery twice. Once from the Google CDN, and again from your directory. This could cause unexpected behavior. Could you provide the complete setup of your page - otherwise finding the error is complicated.

Comment: Please also check the JavaScript Developer Console of your Browser for errors. In the most cases it tells you whats wrong with your code (But sometimes it is a bit cryptic ;) )

Comment: Could it be some kind of a conflict between the css/js files?

Comment: No there isn't a conflict possibility between js and css.

Comment: I meant between the js scripts or between the css files, not between js and css files.

Comment: Ok - in your paste are some serious syntax errors. I have corrected them, but I think syntax is not your only problem. (http://pastebin.com/JAVbuEpM). For better learning and deeper understanding: remove anything you do not have a clue what it does, or what it is good for. After that add anything step by step, and watch what happens. And if you then got an error come back again, and ask specific Question on your error. This way nobody can help you properly. 
Of course, it is possible that there are conflicts between your files.

Comment: I see. Oh, well, I'll go deep maybe I'll get the problem. Still not working with the corrected syntax above, but thanks.

Comment: As I said, syntax is not your only Problem ;-) Go deep - and then, ask deep.

Comment: Sorry for one more comment, but I put all the JS scripts references in the index in a big comment and it seems that the problem isn't coming from some sort of a conflict between those files. Could it rather be that some elements on that certain page aren't allowing the box to overlap(CSS wise)?

Answer (score 0):

It should work...[See](http://jsfiddle.net/PLdbr/129/)

I think you have missed the Jquery should load on top.

And your Width of the popup should be Auto. Unless it will expand the window.

```
.popbox {
  width: auto;
  ...
```

Comment: Left it on auto, tho', but the pop-up isn't showing.

Comment: I think the Problem is with the variable moveLeft in js.. so set moveLeft = 5;by default.. lem me know is it works?

Comment: see this its working for me http://jsfiddle.net/PLdbr/129/   is your problem solved?

Comment: I did, used your sources from the fiddle above.

Comment: No. It must be a CSS problem I can't seem to find(uncommenting all the other JS files showed that there isn't any conflict between those).

Comment: increase the z-index .popbox to 10000 like that.. it should z-index problem

Comment: If I leave the cursor standing still on the word that should make the box appear and then I press F5, it appears and stay there, but if I leave and try to hover again, it doesn't appear anymore(that with position: absolute, not with fixed).

Comment: I edited the question. Seems that without the code responsible for moving the box together with the cursor, it appears and dissapears just fine. Any ideas?